# Hook a search form anywhere on the site, using a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, search, forms

I'm new and I apologize if I ask an already existing question. But I can't find the information I'm looking for.

I need to know how a search form works in wordpress.

I'm creating a custom theme and would like to insert a search form and use a plugin instead of the theme itself to handle requests.

But I'm not aware of how exactly wordpress works.

Do I have to use hooks? How do I use them?
Can I find this information in the documentation?
Where ?

In summary, my site has a form, it has to send a request, like searching for a book title, and it has to be processed by the plug-in.

Thanks in advance to everyone. I hope I was clear.

### More information

I want to clarify that the plugin that processes my request example: Searching for a book title in the database, works on specific custom tables of the plugin. While this is probably incorrect, I need it to store and manage "books" exclusively in this case.

Comment: the term captured doesn't make a lot of sense in WordPress terminology, specifically because the answer to the question is not very useful for what you want to do, and **heavily** dependent on how you plan to build your custom search functionality

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more understandable.

Comment: I would look into custom post types, a custom post type named `book` is a common example in tutorials and on the official developer docs, custom tables usually bring with them a heavy burden on the developer as they need to build admin UIs from scratch, query things with raw SQL by hand, and then build out URLs and templates from scratch. CPT's do all that for you, and extra data can be stored in post meta and taxonomy terms. Unless you're planning to store data with unique storage and query requirements e.g. storing and querying longitudes and latitudes, tables are rarely faster

Comment: this is because most people aren't aware of how to index their tables and design them for fast performance, and don't plan ahead the queries they intend to use and design their tables accordingly. Those that do see improvements usually see it because they misused post meta/custom fields in ways that aren't performant instead of using faster methods. The best use of raw SQL WPDB APIs is for interacting with the tables of 3rd party applications, e.g. bridging WP and PHPBB

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how a wordpress search form works.

It's a form tag with an input that has the name `s` on the search field.

Likewise `example.com/archive/?s=term` will work on any post archive and narrow it down to just the search term "term". *There is nothing special about the search form itself*.

Likewise searches can be triggered with no search form whatsoever by specifying the `s` query parameter.

WordPress knows if a page is a search results page based on the `is_search` function which checks on the `s` parameter of the main query ( a `WP_Query` object ).

> I'm creating a custom tempa and would like to insert a search form and use a plugin instead of the theme itself to handle requests.

This is what you should have asked about, and you should have provided significantly more detail. Wether the theme or a plugin handles the request is irrelevant here, the code to do it would be almost identical in either case. Aside from theme templates and the order things are loaded in there is zero sandboxing between plugins and themes. A filter works the same wether it's in `functions.php` or a plugin.

> In summary, my site has a form, it needs to submit a request, and it needs to be captured by the plugin.

This has nothing to do with search other than that it's conceptually related from a users point of view. *Ignore WordPress search it is a red herring and a distraction, a source of confusion.* It has nothing to do with your problem or the solution.

You need:

- a form
- a place to submit the form, aka the `action="...` part, maybe a page, maybe the same page, there is no canonical golden solution to this that you should always use, lots of plugins do different things
- a way to identify when the form is submitted, perhaps a known URL parameter or a hidden input if you're `POST`'ing

  - when it's submitted run your code and fetch results
  - make sure the name of the field is not reserved, if you reuse a name used by a query variable WP uses it will be picked up and put into the main query, leading to conflicts
  - then display the results, perhaps via a block/shortcode/widget, or loading a custom template, or maybe by submitting to a page which can have a theme template or something else, there is no single answer to this part, there are lots and lots of options with tradeoffs.

At this point, any tutorial on how to build a form in a theme would answer most of your questions and provide vital reference points to let you figure out what it is that you need to do and what you need to know.

Comment: **Thanks a lot for the exhaustive answer.** Sorry for the terms used **incorrectly**. I try to learn, I'm new to using wordpress and it fascinated me.